# Java Recursion - Where are these values coming from?

Tags: java, recursion

I am confused about the following code. I have no idea where the values are coming from that end up being assigned to the variable "temp".  Somehow, magically, the values of 2 and 4 end up being assigned.

When the power() method is executed and y > 0, the only thing that happens within the method is for the power() method to call itself, and I see nothing that could return a value of a 2 or a 4 from that method.

I understand that the code is correct, and that this is a recursive call, but I'm trying to find out, specifically, what line of code within the power() method is returning those values which end up getting assigned to the temp variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;      
    System.out.println("Value returned is: " + power(x,y));
}
public static int power (int x, int y)
{
    if (y <= 0)
    {
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       int temp = power(x, y - 1);                                   
       System.out.println("Value of temp before is: " + temp);
       System.out.println("Value of x is: " + x);
       System.out.println("value of z before is: " + z);              
       z = x* temp;          
       System.out.println("value of z after is: " + z);
       System.out.println("Value of temp after is: " + temp);
       System.out.println("***********************************************");  
       return z;
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Value of temp before is: 1          <==This is assigned 1 by return 1;
Value of x is: 2
value of z before is: 0
value of z after is: 2
Value of temp after is: 1
**********************************
Value of temp before is: 2         <==This is assigned by return z returning to power() method call
Value of x is: 2
value of z before is: 2
value of z after is: 4
Value of temp after is: 2
**********************************
Value of temp before is: 4         <==This is assigned by return z returning to power() method call
Value of x is: 2
value of z before is: 4
value of z after is: 8
Value of temp after is: 4
**********************************
Value returned is: 8
```

Comment: One of the two `return` statements depending on preconditions.

Comment: Is it the "return z" code that returns the 1, 2, and 4?

Comment: `return z` returns the `2` and `4`, `return 1` returns the `1`. Step through the code with a debugger and keep track of the calls to `power(...)` and the values of the parameters that are being passed.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just figured it out.  It's the "return z" statement.  I changed it to "return 4" and all of my display statements for temp showed temp had a value of 4.

Comment: Jonny, yes, I wasn't very clear in my question.  I knew where 1 was coming from, just didn't see where the 2 and the 4 were coming from.  Now this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that every time I ask a question, it's marked as unhelpful and is put "On Hold" for various reasons.  That surely doesn't inspire me to ask further questions, which is what I thought this website was for.

Answer (score 3):

1. `power()` is called with 2 and 3 as arguments.
2. this line `int temp = power(x, y - 1);` calls a new instance of `power()` with 2 and 2 as arguments
3. the same thing happens, again, but with 2 and 1 as arguments
4. finally, the last instance of `power()` is called with 2 and 0 as arguments
5. for the first time, the `if (y <= 0)` condition is true, so this instance of the `power()` call executes the statement `return 1;`.
6. the previous instance of `power()` takes that result (1) and executes `z = x* temp;` with it, resulting in a value of 2. It returns that value.
7. the next instance of `power()` does the same, multiplying the result by x (2) and getting 4.
8. the final instance of `power()` (the first one that was called, which was waiting on all of the recursive calls it initiated) finally gets back the value of 4 from the recursive calls, multiplies it by x (2) and gets 8 as the final answer.

See Wikipedia for more general info on recursion and how it works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

The main idea is that the method simplifies the problem and then calls itself again, until one of the calls gets to a 'base case'. The base case here is:

```
if (y <= 0)
{
   return 1;
}
```

Once the base case is solved the other cases can be solved based on the result of the base case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.  This was very helpful.

Comment: Your could improve this answer by talking about _activations_ of power() instead of instances.  "Instance" makes it sound like there is more than one copy of the method, which is not true, and a noob could confuse it with instances of the _class_.

Answer (score 1):

Each time around the calls to `power` the current values of the arguments are pushed onto a method stack (look up "stack" in references on data structures). You have to trace the execution with a pen and paper ("pen testing") or in your mind using the new values for each different call. Like this:

```
x=2 y=3 temp = power(2, 2)
        x=2 y=2 temp = power(2, 1)
                x=2 y=1 temp = power(2, 0)
                    x=2  y=0  return 1
                temp = 1
                z = 2 * temp = 2 * 1 = 2
                return 2
        temp = 2
        z = 2 * 2 = 4
        return 4
temp = 4
z = 2 * temp = 2 * 4 = 8
return 8
```

Comment: I like the visual this answer provides even though the summary could be worded better

Comment: Thank you very much for the data example.  This helps a lot!